# Google App Engine User API vs Google+ Social Sign-on Plugin

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-plus-signin

I was just wondering is there any philosophical differences between GAE Java User API and Google+ social plugin sign-on?

Both seems to served the core purpose, which is to authenticate a user against his/her Google account.

Hope someone can enlighten me.

Referneces :

https://developers.google.com/+/web/

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/users/

Answer (score 0):

GAE Users service can be used pretty much only for login to a specific GAE application, while Google+ sign in can be used to interact with any Google API. For example, if you need to know even a basic detail such as the user's full name, the Users service can't help you there.
The Users service is more "transparently coupled" to the user's session in Google - once the user has signed in, assuming they checked "remember me", they will keep being signed in as long as they don't delete the cookie, and you as a developer don't need to do any special check. With Google+ sign in you need to check whether the user is signed in on each visit and handle expired tokens yourself (though client libraries help with it).

Comment: Thank you for the kind insights. From implementing point of view, i'll guess i stick with the User API since the requirements is just to consume the existing Cloud services.